# Is there a way to fixing my slow computer without SSD, Lightweight Linux. and RAM and CPU upgrade?

Tags: linux, windows-7, hard-drive, memory, ssd

I start a my old acer veriton m420 computer. and now open chrome on windows 7 computer. it slow for 1 minutes. and then page unresponsive.

I have tried:

Uninstall unused programs. (AP)

Delete temporary files. Whenever you use internet Explorer all your browsing history remains in the depths of your PC.

Install a solid state drive. (Samsung)

Get more hard drive storage. (WD)

Stop unnecessary start ups.

Get more RAM.

Run a disk defragment.

Run a disk clean-up.

Any Lightweight Linux OS.

Comment: Short answer. Not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This computer is close to 9 years old, so it will never be particularly fast.

I would run some benchmarks on it - if you are running both an SSD and HDD it could be that the hdd is dying. If its SSD based, check the SSD as well - I have seen some SSDs become painfully slow over time.

Relatedly, try setting vm.swappiness to 5 (google vm.swappiness distroname to find out how for your distro - this can reduce swapping and increase interactivity)

Im not an AMD expert, but also check your CPU clock speed when the system us under load to ensure its not throttling due to a clogged cpu/fan - if it is, try cleaning this.

Run vmstat -n2 in a window while doing things that you are trying to speed up so you can see what resource is being bottleneck so you know what to fix.